# Create a dropdown list for members on the front page of my site

Tags: sql, sql-server, list, umbraco, dropdown

I are using umbraco 7.

I want to create a drop down list of members (From MSSql) on the front page of my site.

I have a nuPicker Sql Dropdown setup in datatypes and can load this in the back office fine.

Now I want to get it on the front screen.

Once there it needs to load a whole heap of custom information.

Before changing needs to test custom information and warn if needs to be saved because of changes.

Who do I do this

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out.

Don't use nuPicker

```
public IEnumerable<Some Model> GetData()
{
  var db = applicationContext.Current.Database.Database;
  var tbl = db.Fetch<Some Model>(@" Some Sql Script ");
  return tbl;
}


public List<SelectListItem> BuildDropDown()
{
   List<SelectListItem> lst = new List<SelectListItem>
   IEnumerable< Some Model> Members = GetData();

   for each item in Members)
   {
      lst.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = item.Label, Text = item.Label });
   }
}
```